# WebBrowser control in .net for windows ce

Tags: c#, compact-framework, webbrowser-control

when I navigate to particular page using WebBrowser control in .net for windows ce device, it is not taking clicks for buttons on page.e.g Search button on Google page..

Actually this works for 1 device and not for other..

Can anybody help out solving this?

Comment: Which devices? SmartPhones or PocketPc touch screens? where does it work and where not? Which windows mobile version?

Comment: @Davide: both are PocketPc devices

Comment: the problem is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689030/google-search-is-not-working-in-web-browser-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to set registry, and keys that need be set are;

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings and the value that need to set is "WarnOnZoneCrossing" to '0' in current user registry.

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3 and the value that need to set is "1601"to '0' and "1609" to '0' in local machine registry.

**The code will look like**

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey (@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", true))
            {
                if (key == null)
                {                    Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings");
                    using (RegistryKey newKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", true))
                    {
                        newKey.SetValue("WarnOnZoneCrossing", 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                    key.SetValue("WarnOnZoneCrossing", 0);
            }
            //enable submission of non-encrypted form data
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3", true))
            {
                if (key == null)
                {
                    Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3");
                    using (RegistryKey newKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3", true))
                    {
                        newKey.SetValue("1601", 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                    key.SetValue("1601", 0);
            }
            //enable the display of mixed content
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3", true))
            {
                if (key == null)
                {
                    Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3");
                    using (RegistryKey newKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3", true))
                    {
                        newKey.SetValue("1609", 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                    key.SetValue("1609", 0);
            }
```